# Not showing view page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm not sure how to do this because its not echoing my html. Its showing the div tag in firebug but not anything else after it which should be either the index page(homepage) or my 404 page. What's supposed to happen is its supposed to find out which page view its supposed to load via the if statement and then load load that view inside the content page.

Controller:

```
 $siteInfo = $this->kow->getSiteTitleAndSlogan();
 $activeTemplate = $this->kow->getTemplate();
 if ($this->kow->pageStatus('index', $activeTemplate[0]->short_name) == 1){
     $page = $this->load->view($activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/pages/index'); 
 } else {
     $page = $this->load->view($activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/pages/404'); 
 }
 $footerLinks = $this->kow->getFooterNav(); 
 $this->template
 ->title($siteInfo[0]->site_name,$siteInfo[0]->site_slogan)
 ->prepend_metadata('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/assets/css/'.$activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'.css" />')
 ->set('footerLinks', $footerLinks)
 ->set('page', $page)               
 ->set_partial('header', $activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/header')
 ->set_partial('navigation', $activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/navigation')            
 ->set_partial('content', $activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/content')
 ->set_partial('footer', $activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/footer')
 ->build('kow');

if ($this->kow->pageStatus('index', $activeTemplate[0]->short_name) == 1){
      $page = $this->load->view($activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/pages/index'); 
} else {
      $page = $this->load->view($activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/pages/404'); 
}
```

View:

```
<div id="content">
<?php 
echo $page; 
?>
</div>
```

EDIT: What I'm trying to do is take the id of the active template and the string index to the pageStatus function and find out if the status of the page has a value of 1. When I run the print_r function like below I get this:

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [status_id] => 1 ) )
```

Controller

```
if ($this->kow->pageStatus('index', $activeTemplate[0]->id) == 1){
    $page = $this->load->view($activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/pages/index', '', true); 
} else {
    $page = $this->load->view($activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/pages/404', '', true); 
}
print_r($this->kow->pageStatus('index', $activeTemplate[0]->id));
```

EDIT 2: I'm still not getting the right page to view.

Comment: Which view is that code from?

Comment: That was from the content view NOT the index view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're loading the views for index and 404 into the `$page` variable incorrectly. To store the output of a `$this->load->view()` call you must include `true` as the third parameter.

From the CI user guide

Returning views as data

There is a third optional parameter lets you change the behavior of the function so that it returns data as a string rather than sending it to your browser. This can be useful if you want to process the data in some way. If you set the parameter to true (boolean) it will return data. The default behavior is false, which sends it to your browser. Remember to assign it to a variable if you want the data returned:

```
$string = $this->load->view('myfile', '', true);
```

Also, the last bit of your code, the second definition of `$page` happens after the call to `->set('page', $page)` and `->build('kow');` which therefore won't change the output.

Comment: Thank you for the response. How do I fix the second part of your response?

Comment: Actually I have it echoing now, however, for some reason its not showing the index page. Its showing the 404 page.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about code igniter, but as i see this. I think $page might be a TEMPLATE object and it is not meant to be displayed using ECHO naturaly...

OR

Your template fails to render because of a php fatal error but so thats why your buffer contains the initial DIV but nothing else. (Or an EXIT/DIE was called within processing of your ECHO $PAGE)

Answer (score 1):

This "$this->kow->pageStatus('index', $activeTemplate[0]->id)" returns an array. Cant compare it in the way your doing it. Sure it will return 1 which can be interpreted as TRUE but what if the status_id is set to 0 or 2 or something else then it will still return "TRUE".

Hope this helps